# R vs. SPSS mixed model repeated measures code [from Cross Validated]

Tags: r, spss, anova, mixed-models, longitudinal

NOTE: This question was originally posted on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/317841/what-am-i-modeling-with-r-vs-spss-mixed-model/317853?noredirect=1#comment603715_317853), where it was suggested that it should be asked in StackOverflow instead.

---

I am trying to model a 3-way repeated measures experiment, FixedFactorA * FixedFactorB * Time[days]. There are no missing observations, but my groups (FactorA * FactorB) are unequal (close, but not completely balanced). From reading online, the best way to model a repeated measures experiment in which observation order matters (due to the response mean and variance changing in a time-dependent way) and for unequal groups is to use a mixed model and specify an appropriate covariance structure.  **However, I am new to the idea of mixed models and I am confused as to whether I am using the correct syntax to model what I am trying to model.**

I would like to do a full factorial analysis, such that I could detect significant time * factor interactions.  For example, for subjects with FactorA = 1, their responses over time might have a different slope and/or intercept than subjects with FactorA =2.  I also want to be able to check whether certain combinations of FactorA and FactorB have significantly different responses over time (hence the full three-way interaction term).

From reading online, it seems like AR1 is a reasonable covariance structure for longitudinal-like data, so I decided to try that.  Also, I saw that one is supposed to use ML if one plans to compare two different models, so I chose that approach in anticipation of needing to fine-tune the model.  It is also my understanding that the goal is to minimize the AIC during model selection.

This is the code in the log for what I tried in SPSS (for long-form data), which yielded an AIC of 2471:

```
MIXED RESPONSE BY FactorA FactorB Day
  /CRITERIA=CIN(95) MXITER(100) MXSTEP(10) SCORING(1) SINGULAR(0.000000000001) HCONVERGE(0,
ABSOLUTE) LCONVERGE(0, ABSOLUTE) PCONVERGE(0.000001, ABSOLUTE)
  /FIXED=FactorA FactorB Day FactorA*FactorB FactorA*Day FactorB*Day FactorA*FactorB*Day | SSTYPE(3)
  /METHOD=ML
  /PRINT=SOLUTION TESTCOV
  /REPEATED=Day | SUBJECT(Subject_ID) COVTYPE(AR1)
```

This is what I tried in R, which yielded an AIC of 2156:

```
    require(nlme)

    #output error fix: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40647/lme-error-iteration-limit-reached 

    ctrl <- lmeControl(opt='optim')  #I used this b/c otherwise I get the iteration limit reached error

    fit1 <- lme(RESPONSE ~ Day*FactorA*FactorB, random = ~ Day|Subject_ID, control=ctrl,
        correlation=corAR1(form=~Day), data, method="ML")

    summary(fit1)
```

These are my questions:

1. The SPSS code above yielded a model with AIC = 2471, while the R code yielded a model with AIC = 2156.  What is it about the codes that makes the models different?
2. From what I described above, are either of these models appropriate for what I am trying to test? If not, what would be a better way, and how would I do it in both programs to get the same results?

***Edits***

Another thing to note is that I didn't dummy-code my factors.  I don't know if this is a problem for either software, or if the built-in coding is different in SPSS vs R.  I also don't know if this will be a problem for my three-way interaction term.

Also, when I say "factor", I mean an unchanging group or characteristic (like "sex").

Comment: If you take "Day" out as a random slope from the `lme` model, is the AIC between models more similar (i.e., use `random = ~1|Subject_ID)`?  I know very little SPSS syntax, but I don't think the "repeated" syntax is indicative of a random slope.

Comment: I had tried `random = ~1|Subject_ID`, and the AIC (2160) is still pretty far off from the SPSS one.  However, I honestly care more about specifying an appropriate model in R, since people seem to prefer that for mixed models over SPSS.

Answer (score 0):

Start with an unconditional model, one with an identity variance-covariance structure at level-1 and one with an AR(1) var-covar structure at level 1:

```
unconditional.identity<-lme(RESPONSE~Day, random=~Day|Subject_ID, data=data, method='ML')
unconditional.ar1<-lme(RESPONSE~Day, random=~Day|Subject_ID, correlation=corAR1(form=~Day), data=data, method='ML')
```

Find the intra-class correlation coefficient of this unconditional model, which is the level-2 error divided by the sum of level-1 and level-2 errors. This is probably easier in a spreadsheet program, but in R:

`intervals(unconditional.identity)$reStruct$Subject_ID[2]^2/(intervals(unconditional.identity)$reStruct$Subject_ID[2]^2+intervals(unconditional.identity)$sigma[2]^2)`

`intervals(unconditional.ar1)$reStruct$Subject_ID[2]^2/(intervals(unconditional.ar1)$reStruct$Subject_ID[2]^2+intervals(unconditional.ar1)$sigma[2]^2)`

It depends on your field, but in educational research, an ICC below 0.2, definitely below 0.1, is considered not ready for hierarchical linear models. That is to say, multiple regression would be better because the assumption of independence is confirmed. If your ICC is below a cutoff for your field, then do not use a hierarchical longitudinal model.

If your ICC is acceptable for hierarchical linear models, then add in your control grouping variable with identity and AR(1) var-covar matrix:

```
conditional1.identity<-lme(RESPONSE~Day+Group, random=~Day+Group|Subject_ID, data=data, method='ML')
conditional1.ar1<-lme(RESPONSE~Day+Group, random=~Day+Group|Subject_ID, correlation=corAR1(form=~Day), data=data, method='ML')
```

If your factors are time-invariant (which you said on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/317841/what-am-i-modeling-with-r-vs-spss-mixed-model/317853?noredirect=1#comment603717_317853)), then your model gets bigger because time and group are nested in these fixed effects:

```
conditional2.identity<-lme(RESPONSE~Day+Group+FactorA+FactorB+FactorA*Day+FactorB*Day+FactorA*Group+FactorB*Group+FactorB, random=~Day+Group|Subject_ID, data=data, method='ML')
conditional2.ar1<-lme(Day+Group+FactorA+FactorB+FactorA*Day+FactorB*Day+FactorA*Group+FactorB*Group+FactorB, random=~Day+Group|Subject_ID, correlation=corAR1(form=~Day), data=data, method='ML')
```

You can get confidence intervals on the coefficients with `intervals()` or p-values with `summary()`. Remember, `lme` reports error terms in standard deviation format.

I do not know your area of study, so I can't say if your three-way interaction effect makes theoretical sense. But your model is getting quite dense at this point. The more parameters you estimate, the more degrees of freedom the model has when you compare them, so the statistical significance will be biased. If you are really interested in a three-way interaction effect, I suggest you consider the theoretical meaning of such an interaction and what it would mean if such an interaction did occur. Nonetheless, you can estimate it by adding it to the code above:

```
conditional3.identity<-lme(RESPONSE~Day+Group+FactorA+FactorB+FactorA*Day+FactorB*Day+FactorA*Group+FactorB*Group+FactorB+Day*FactorA*FactorB, random=~Day+Group|Subject_ID, data=data, method='ML')
conditional3.ar1<-lme(Day+Group+FactorA+FactorB+FactorA*Day+FactorB*Day+FactorA*Group+FactorB*Group+FactorB+Day*FactorA*FactorB, random=~Day+Group|Subject_ID, correlation=corAR1(form=~Day), data=data, method='ML')
```

Finally, compare the nested models:

`anova(unconditional.identity,conditional1.identity,conditional2.identity,conditional3.identity)`

`anova(unconditional.ar1,conditional1.ar1,conditional2.ar1,conditional3.ar1)`

Like I said, the more parameters you estimate, the more biased your statistical significance will be: i.e., more parameters = more degrees of freedom = less chance of a statistically significant model.

**HOWEVER**, the best part about multi-level models is comparing effect sizes, so then you don't have to worry about p-values at all. Effect sizes are in the form of a "proportional reduction in variance explained."

This is comparing models. For example, to comapre the proportional reduction in variance explained in level 1 from the unconditional model to the conditional1 model:

`(intervals(unconditional.identity)$sigma[2]^2 - intervals(conditional1.identity)$sigma[2]^2) / intervals(unconditional.identity)$sigma[2]^2`

Hopefully you can "plug and play" the same code for the number of level-2 error terms you have (which is more than one in some of your cases). Make sure to compare only nested models in this way.

Comment: So my response variable is essentially a measure of learning.  I expect performance to improve with successive day.  I am interested in whether my group factors (such as sex) impact the learning curve, either the starting point or the slope.  Does that help?

Comment: One potential issue is that I don't really care about the ideal predictive model; I am really trying to validly  **test the terms in the model for significance**--so I think **I *want* p-values.**  The overall model isn't really useful to me, other than making sure it doesn't violate assumptions.

Comment: ...unless I used the model comparison thing to indirectly measuring significance by comparing models with and without a given term, and use the p-value from that comparison test.  Is that what you mean?  I am really trying to upgrade this analysis from a three-way repeated measures ANOVA to a method that is more valid for a time variable.  I am more used to seeing 2-way ANOVAs, or repeated measures ANOVA methods that only look at the first and last day of learning and ignore the intervening days.

Comment: You bring up a lot of really interesting points, especially since you are talking about learning (I'm an educational psychologist). I suggest two things: 1) research the meaning of statistical significance. A p-value if often interpreted as the probability of a result given your data, i.e. p(r|d), but that is incorrect. A p-value is the probability of your data given your result! See Kline (2004).

Comment: 2) always always have a hypothesis that has evidence. If you are interested in the effect of sex/gender on achievement, do a literature review. There is a lot of research on this topic. If you want to talk more about this, I'd love to discuss it with you. Tweet me @jsraadt.

Comment: This is for a specific experiment with a specific subject population that has not been previously performed in the literature. Thus, a literature review would not be relevant in this case.  In regards to p-values, I am performing this analysis for a colleague, and I have a feeling that the field of study (and therefore my colleague) may be strongly biased toward p-value significance (regardless of the merits of this view).  However, I agree that you raise a very good point in that regard.